# Insert data inside SQS queue in order into DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-sqs

Can we have multiple lines in an sqs message and insert them in order to dynamodb? for example if i have multiple sqs queues by departments and  inside queue i have list of employees which have attributes like employee id, dept id, first name, last name  and i should iterate the contents of queue in ascending order of employee id and insert employee id, dept id, first name, last name into dynamodb table.

Comment: Yes, you can insert data into dynamodb. No, you cannot get messages from a queue ordered by some criteria, you either get them randomly or in case of fifo queues you get them in the order they were inserted in, but you cannot get messages ordered by the employee id.

Comment: Thank you luk2302, what i mean is that let the order be random inside queue i will iterate based on employee id and insert in order. But will an SQS queue let me have multiple employee ids in one queue?

Comment: SQS does not care about the contents of your message (apart from a length constraint), you can put whatever you want in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I read, it looks like you want the employee data kept sorted by id in Dynamodb.

First, SQS doesn't do sorting on your demand/customization. It does provide FIFO (first in first out) queues which are based on the order you insert the messages.

Even if SQS does have the feature you wanted and you can insert message/data to dynamodb in your preferred order, it doesn't gurantee you having the data sorted in dynamodb and sorted in your query results.

In order to have data sorted in DynamoDB table and reflected on your query results, you'll need to use sort key (range attribute).

Here are few options you can try on DynamoDB table design.

1. dept id as partition key + employee id as sort key

With this setup, you have your employee data sorted within one department when you do queries.

2. create an attribute/column named "everyone", set value to 1 when inserting the records. Then you can create GSI (Global Secondary Index) with everyone as partition key and employeeId as sort key.

With this setup, you have your all employee data sorted by employee ids, regardless department id. It should work well if your GSI size is below a few gigabytes.

Also, you can combine option 1 and option 2 together to archive sorting employees both on campany level and department level.